# Discord bot extensions with same Object

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I need to use the same object in multiple extensions (cogs). How to edit my simple bot example to achieve this?

I can initiate SHARED_OBJECT in my main.py or in cog files also. The main point is to use the same object in COG1 and COG2 extensions. It is important to consider that every extension can be reloaded after program start.

I'm using [discord.py rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html) lib

main.py

```
client = Bot(description="Bot", command_prefix="!")
client.run(__token__)    
SHARED_OBJECT = SomeObject()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    client.dev = True
    print('[Discord] Logged in as {} (ID:{}) | Connected to {}  servers'.format(client.user.name,client.user.id,1))

    client.load_extension('COG1')
    client.load_extension('COG2')
```

COG1.PY class

```
class COG1():
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self):
    print()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(COG1(bot))
```

COG1.PY class

```
class COG2():
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self):
    print("test")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(COG2(bot))
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do it is to set it as a property on your bot.
Example:

```
bot.my_variable = SHARED_OBJECT
```

You have indeed access to the bot istance in every extension.

Answer (score 0):

If your cogs all rely on this shared object, then you should ask yourself if their functionality is really independent enough to be split into different modules.

That said, if you write your own `load_extension`, then you can write `setup` methods that take this shared object and pass it to the class `__init__`.  I cribbed the below off the [actual implementation](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L667), removing some of the validations for brevity.

cog1.py: (same changes to cog2)

```
class COG1():
    def __init__(self, bot, sharedobj):
        self.bot = bot
        self.sharedobj = sharedobj

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self):
        print()

def setup(bot, sharedobj):
    bot.add_cog(COG1(bot, sharedobj))
```

main.py

```
import importlib

def load_extension(name, bot, sharedobj):
    if name in self.extensions:
        return
    lib = importlib.import_module(name)
    lib.setup(bot, sharedobj)
    bot.extensions[name] = lib

SHARED_OBJECT = SomeObject()

load_extension('COG1', SHARED_OBJECT)
load_extension('COG2', SHARED_OBJECT)
```

Comment: I can't get this to work:
lib.setup(bot, sharedobj) TypeError: setup() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @Mindau My bad.  Make sure to use the local `load_extension` instead of `client.load_extension`.  You also need to make sure that all your `setup` functions take 2 arguments